# CQRS: How to implement eventual consistency between MongoDB (read model) and SQL Server (write model)

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a project using the CQRS design pattern with domain driven design. In the read side of this project, I use a materialized view to build the read model so that read side and write side can be updated to be consistent by SQL Server.

I would like to refactor my project and use MongoDB for the read side. I don`t know much about MongoDB. Is there any algorithm or strategy to keep data consistent between a NoSQL database (MongoDB) and a relational database (SQL Server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To synchronize data storages your queries (read side) and commands (write side) you can use one of the following strategies:

- **Synchronous** - Every command also synchronously update query side data storage
- **Asynchronous** - Every command triggers asynchronous update of query side data storage
- **Scheduled** - A predefined job runs periodically and updates query side data storage
- **On-demand** - Query side data storage is updated on-demand. For example when a request comes and you have a some sort of algorithm that triggers updating if staleness of data is detected.

So, it's up to you to figure out what strategy best applies to your project.

Only with **synchronous** approach you got strong consistency.
Other options causes eventual consistency and they differ how much long the data could be stale. In **asynchronous** approach you have stale data in terms of milliseconds.